# Can't run localhost PHP server on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, localhost

So i've done this before but I don't remember the command. I was able to use a directory a localhost file. I've tried `sudo apachectl start` but when I go to `localhost` the page isn't found. I've also tried restarting the server, but the result was still the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up apache using a `.conf` file?

For local development environments, it's usually recommended to create a new `.conf`file for apache using your username:

1. Terminal: `sudo nano -w /etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf`

   where USERNAME is the result of `whoami`
2. And then put this in there:

   `<Directory "/Users/USERNAME/Sites/">
   Options Indexes Multiviews
   AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory>`
3. `sudo apachectl restart`

Here's a reference link for future use:

http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo -v` in a terminal and paste these lines:

```
echo '<Directory "/Users/'$USER'/Sites/">
  Options Indexes Multiviews
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>'|sudo tee /etc/apache2/users/$USER.conf
sudo sed -i '' 's/#\(LoadModule php5_module.*\)/\1/p' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
sudo apachectl restart
mkdir -p ~/Sites
echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>'>~/Sites/test.php
sleep 1
open http://localhost/~$USER/test.php
```

`sudo apachectl start` enables Apache. `/usr/sbin/apachectl` is a shell script in OS X and `apachectl start` just runs `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`. Modifying `/etc/apache2/users/$USER.conf` is needed to make `http://localhost/~username/` work.

You can enable PHP by uncommenting `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and running `sudo apachectl restart`.